# why AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext doesn't implement addBeanFactoryPostProcessor method of ConfigurableWebServerApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot

I'm reading spring-boot bootstrap source code recently. But I find that the ***AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext*** class doesn't implement the *addBeanFactoryPostProcessor* method of ***ConfigurableWebServerApplicationContext*** interface, and the *addBeanFactoryPostProcessor* doesn't have a default implementation. why is this case, is there something i missed? Hope someone gives me a help, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the *addBeanFactoryPostProcessor* method is implemented by another super abstract class **AbstractApplicationContext**